# JHipster: Invalid values not being detected

Tags: jhipster, jackson-databind

I was using JHipster, with its autogenerated code. And ran into the following issue regarding detecting whether the request is valid or not based on the following:
I have a schema of the following:

```yaml
movie:
      type: object
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        director:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        rating:
          type: number
          maximum: 5
          minimum: 0
      example:
        title: The Dark Knight
        director: Christopher Nolan
        description: |
          When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, Batman must accept one of the greatest psychological and physical tests of his ability to fight injustice. 
        rating: 4.5
      required:
        - title
        - director
        - description
        - rating
```

And I have a  test case that invokes the API with the body:

```json
{
    "director":"director",
    "title":true,
    "description":"description",
    "rating":4.5
}
```

However, I am getting the response

```json
{
    "title": "true",
    "director": "director",
    "description": "description",
    "rating": 4.5
}
```

It is not detecting that the parameter "title" is of type boolean not string, causing the testcase to fail. Interestingly, the error validation detects the error when it is set to null, but not when it is boolean.

I have tried debugging by looking at the way the json is parsed by JHipster. However, it is parsing it as a string, not as a Boolean value.

The implemented delegator

```java
    @Service
    @Slf4j
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class Api implements DefaultApiDelegate {
        static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        private final NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest = null;
        static List<Movie> movies = null;
        private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties = new ApplicationProperties();
    
        @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}") 
        private String applicationName;
     
        @Override
        public Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
            return Optional.ofNullable(nativeWebRequest);
        }
    
        @Override
        public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> allMovieGet() {
            getMovies();
            System.out.println("GET request");
            ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> res = new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movies.subList(0, 24), HttpStatus.OK);;
            
            return res;
        }
        
        @Override   
        public ResponseEntity<Movie> addMoviePost(Movie movie){
            getMovies();
            System.out.println(movie.toString());
            System.out.println(movie.getTitle().getClass());
            movies.add(movie);
            ResponseEntity<Movie> res = new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movies.get(movies.size()-1), HttpStatus.CREATED);
            return res;
        }
    
        public void getMovies(){
            try {
                movies = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/movies.json"), new TypeReference<List<Movie>>(){});
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    }
```

I have not made any other changes to the autogenerated code from JHipster's generate-sources. It is a very simple API that I was creating for a prototype

Comment: Please show code for resource controller and arguments  (DTO if you use one). With API-first approach, JHipster generates  interfaces and the implementation vastly depends on manual coding.

Comment: Edited original post for the code that I manually coded. If it helps the rest of the code is autogenerated by JHipster's auto-code generation (the openapi generator that uses an openapi spec to autogenerate code). The request validation is the default one created by JHipster

Comment: I just wrote a test that shows it is related to Jackson not JHipster: 

        var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        var movie = mapper.readValue("{\"title\": true}", Movie.class);
        assertThat(movie.getTitle()).isNotNull().isEqualTo("true");

Comment: Hmm. Does JHipster use Jackson as its default parser? Is there a way to disable or edit this so it parses it as a boolean value instead of a string?

Comment: I don't know, I tagged your question with jackson-databind so that it gets more exposure. Jackson is the default parser from Spring Boot/Spring MVC, so again not specific to JHipster. Title of your question is not focused enough, it should be about unquoted JSON strings